# How to convert substrings to integers simultaneously and storing them for future use?

Tags: java, substring

I am reading certain parts of a text file and displaying it on the command window. The substrings are actually numbers. I want to convert that text to Strings when I do something like

> int real_numbers =
>   Integer.parseInt(number);

it gives an error :

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For
>   input string: "0.0091"    at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown
>   Source)

Below is the code that gives this particular error:

```
String read = "";
String number ="";

for (int linenum=0; linenum<400; linenum++) {
    read = inputFile2.readLine();
    if(read == null){}
    else{
        if (read.startsWith("D")) {
            number = read.substring(9,15);
            System.out.println(number);

            int real_numbers = Integer.parseInt(number); 
            System.out.println(real_numbers);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your if clause could be condensed into just `read != null && read.startsWith("D")`

Comment: if you already find an answer that fits you, you should take a little of your time and register it as accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, 0.0091 isn't an integer.  You probably want

```
Float.parseFloat(number);
```

Comment: is double better to use or a float?

Comment: Double uses more memory, but is more precise.  In your case, it doesn't look like memory usage will be a concern, so probably double.  In fact, you might even want to use BigDecimal.